# Are there any "gotchas" in deploying a Cassandra cluster to a set of Linode VPS instances?

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra, vps, linode

I am learning about the Apache Cassandra database [sic].

Does anyone have any good/bad experiences with deploying Cassandra to less than dedicated hardware like the offerings of Linode or Slicehost?

I think Cassandra would be a great way to scale a web service easily to meet read/write/request load...  just add another Linode running a Cassandra node to the existing cluster.  Yes, this implies running the public web service and a Cassandra node on the same VPS (which many can take exception with).

Pros of Linode-like deployment for Cassandra:

- Private VLAN; the Cassandra nodes could communicate privately
- An API to provision a new Linode (and perhaps configure it with a "StackScript" that installs Cassandra and its dependencies, etc.)
- The price is right

Cons:

- Each host is a VPS and is not dedicated of course
- The RAM/cost ratio is not that great once you decide you want 4GB RAM (cf. dedicated at say SoftLayer)
- Only 1 disk where one would prefer 2 disks I suppose (1 for the commit log and another disk for the data files themselves).  Probably moot since this is shared hardware anyway.

EDIT: found this which helps a bit: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware

I see that 1GB is the minimum but is this a recommendation?  Could I deploy with a Linode 720 for instance (say 500 MB usable to Cassandra)?  See http://www.linode.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How much ram you needs really depends on your workload: if you are write-mostly you can get away with less, otherwise you will want ram for the read cache.

You do get more ram for you money at my employer, rackspace cloud:  http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing.  (our machines also have raided disks so people typically see better i/o performance vs EC2.  Dunno about linode.)

Since with most VPSes you pay roughly 2x for the next-size instance, i.e., about the same as adding a second small instance, I would recommend going with fewer, larger instances than more, smaller ones, since in small numbers network overhead is not negligible.

I do know someone using Cassandra on 256MB VMs but you're definitely in the minority if you go that small.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is what I was hoping. My app is very write-heavy and most of the time, other users that care about oft-written data are going to be long-polling or equivalent and will be pushed the data. Thus, the number of reads will be minimal.

If I go the quorum-writes route I suppose I should always provision an odd number of instances for my Cassandra cluster, yes?

Comment: quorum is a function of replication factor, not total node count.  so your minimum number of nodes (=RF) will be odd but growing past that does not need to be.

Comment: Oh, OK. An example. I could have 1000 nodes in my cluster, but a replication factor of 5.  Quorum would be 5/2+1=3.  Thus, as long as 3 nodes were contacted/written/etc successfully then all is considered successful?